# Registration and Login form

Tags: login, user-registration

I am creating practice website in which i have "register Here" and "login" link on  which I want to open a registration form on click of Register Here and Login Form on click of Login.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with [Theme My Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/). Well written and very functional